# Get all the image pixels with certain pixel values with K-nearest neighbor

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to obtain all the pixels in an image with pixel values closest to certain pixels in an image. For example, I have an image which has a view of ocean (deep blue), clear sky (light blue), beach, and houses. I want to find all the pixels that are closest to deep blue in order to classify it as water. My problem is sky also gets classified as water. Someone suggested to use K nearest neighbor algorithm, but there are few examples online that use old C style. Can anyone provide me example on K-NN using OpenCv C++?

Comment: It would be better if you shared the image in question, and the code that gets the misclassification...and contrast your result to what you think the realistic target for a better classification would be.

Comment: What sort of image is it? Does it have an infrared channel?

Answer (score 0):

"Classify it as water" and "obtain all the pixels in an image with pixel values closest to certain pixels in an image" are not the same task. Color properties is not enough for classification you described. You will always have a number of same colored points on water and sky. So you have to use more detailed analysis. For instance if you know your object is self-connected you can use something like water-shred to fill this region and ignore distant and not connected regions in sky of the same color as water (suppose you will successfully detect by edge-detector horizon-line which split water and sky).

Also you can use more information about object you want to select like structure: calculate its entropy etc. Then you can use also K-nearest neighbor algorithm in multi-dimensional space where 1st 3 dimensions is color, 4th - entropy etc. But you can also simply check every image pixel if it is in epsilon-neighborhood of selected pixels area (I mean color-entropy 4D-space, 3 dimension from color + 1 dimension from entropy) using simple Euclidean metric -- it is pretty fast and could be accelerated by GPU .